# windows file output redirection issue

Tags: windows, perl, ftp, io-redirection

I am trying to redirect the output of an ftp script to a txt file. I expect to find the following format of ftp output towards the end of the file:

```
#this is a part of the complete output after running ftp script via perl
226 Transfer complete
ftp: 100000000 bytes sent in 14.81Seconds 6753.56Kbytes/sec.
ftp> bye
```

This is what is obtained when the command is run on the command prompt. But instead of this I get the following when I redirect the output to a txt file:

```
226 Transfer complete
ftp: 100000000 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.
ftp> 14.816753.56bye
```

For the sake of completeness, I am running an ftp script via perl (using system("ftp -s:script.txt");)and taking its output using '>' on the command line. Could someone please explain what it is that is going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: On the command prompt, does it work via a batch file or is the above output taken from interactive mode ?

Comment: @Kevin i simply give the command:{ perl ftp_upload.pl > out.txt }, which has the command : system("ftp -s:ftp_script.txt");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess after the ftp app writes "ftp: 100000000 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.", it moves back the cursor right before "Seconds" and "Kbytes/sec." to write "14.81" and "6753.56", respectively. If you redirect the output to file, the cursor movement API calls won't work, and these numbers will be appended to the end of the next line.

(I've never seen the code of the Windows ftp app, but I had the same issue in the case of a program I wrote few years ago.)

Comment: When I had a similar problem, the code was mine and I could modify it to avoid cursor repositioning and to use only "serial output". Unfortunately the ftp app cannot be modified... If you really need formatted output, it's very easy to write your own command-line FTP client (e.g. it's about a few hundred lines in C#, see the FtpWebRequest class).

Comment: Or you could use Net::FTP.  Works like a champ for me, even when FTPing to/from a mainframe.